# Oracle activating a MSSQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, odbc, dblink

People, I'm new asking questions around here, and English is not my first language, so have a little patience with me, ok?

I've created a dblink connection between an Oracle 11.2 Database and a MSSQL Server 2008 using [these instructions](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3442661/Making-a-Connection-from-Oracle-to-SQL-Server.htm)

The dblink connection is working and can select data from views and tables. But now, I'm trying to activate a stored procedure in MSSQL Server from the Oracle client.

The stored procedure is already created in MSSQL Server, and the login/user used by the ODBC link can execute the stored procedure in MSSQL, executing the procedure with no errors when activated by the MSSQL Studio. Then, I try to run the stored procedure from the Oracle client, using the following syntax:

```
begin 
    sp_integ_mov_006@test;
end;
```

This results in the following error;

```
Relatório de erros -
ORA-06550: linha 2, coluna 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SP_INTEG_MOV_006@TEST' must be declared
ORA-06550: linha 2, coluna 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Does anyone has some experience with this kind of operation? Has anyone could point me if execute a Mssql stored procedure from Oracle is possible, and maybe some ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLDevelolper, you need to remove the "begin" and "end".